# Fill DTO from two distinct objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following DTO:

```
public int IdTableOne { get; set; }
public string ValueTableOne { get; set; }
public int IdTableTwo { get; set; }
public string ValueTableTwo { get; set; }
```

Also, I have two Models (TableOne & TableTwo) and I fill this models in my repository doing the following code:

```
return dbContext.TableOne;
```

At this point everything it's okay. TableOne & TableTwo are populated, but now I want to return the combination of these values into my DTO object (TableOneId is equal to TableTwoId, it's a relationship between both tables) for doing this I'm trying something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<TableOneAndTwoDTO> GetTableOneAndTwo()
{
    List<TableOneAndTwoDTO> combination = new List<TableOneAndTwoDto>();
    var t1 = myRepository.GetTableOne();
    var t2 = myRepository.GetTableTwo();

    var query = from p in t1
        select new {
            IdTableOne = p.Id,
            ValueTableOne = p.Value,
        };

    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        combination.Add(new TableOneAndTwoDTO { IdTableOne = item.IdTableOne, ValueTableOne = item.ValueTableOne });
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I add the TableTwo values to my DTO only when IdTableOne = IdTableTwo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your table results. Something like this:

```
var query = from p in t1
            join j in t2 on p.IdTableOne equals j.IdTableTwo
            select new { p, j };
```

And then you can add the join values to your DTO using something like this:

```
foreach (var item in query)
{
    combination.Add(new TableOnwAndTwoDTO { IdTableOne = item.p.IdTableOne, IdTableTwo = item.j.IdTableTwo... })
}
```

Comment: Why handle null results from j object? `join` won't leave you with null values: it's not the equivalent of a SQL LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Rigth! Thanks for the comment, I was thinking in doing some left join.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a LINQ Join. You can avoid a lot of the ceremony from your original code by putting the whole thing into one query and then calling `.ToList()` before returning.

```
public IEnumerable<TableOneAndTwoDTO> GetTableOneAndTwo()
{
    var t1 = myRepository.GetTableOne();
    var t2 = myRepository.GetTableTwo();
    var combination =
        from p in t1
        join j in t2 on p.IdTableOne equals j.IdTableTwo
        select new {
            IdTableOne = p.Id,
            ValueTableOne = p.Value,
            IdTableTwo = j.Id,
            ValueTableTwo = j.Value,
        };
     return combination.ToList();
}
```